# Копирование содержимого блоков с одинаковым классом JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Задача при клике на разные блоки с классом "media" копировать их содержимое в блок c классом "tt", чтоб они появлялись один под другим.

Сейчас это не работает, т.к. на какой бы блок ("media") не нажимал, все копируется с первого.

```js
//выбираем нужные элементы
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.media');

//перебираем все найденные элементы и вешаем на них события
[].forEach.call( a, function(el) {
    //вешаем событие
    el.onclick = function(e) {
        //производим действия
        $('#clicker').clone(true).unwrap().appendTo('.tt');
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">54,120</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">12,650</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">32,390</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">76,770</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tt">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.media').click(function(e) {
  $('.tt').append(this.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">54,120</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">12,650</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">32,390</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">76,770</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tt">

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, все оказалось намного проще и меньше кода!!!

Comment: А нет, при таком копировании и новые блоки которые копируются при нажатии делают еще одну копию

Comment: Верно, мне надо чтоб копировалось содержание блока, а не сам блок.

Comment: @4isto в таком случае измени `this.outerHTML` на `this.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

```js
//выбираем нужные элементы
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.media');

//перебираем все найденные элементы и вешаем на них события
[].forEach.call( a, function(el) {
    //вешаем событие
    el.onclick = function(e) {
        //производим действия
        $(this).clone(true).unwrap().appendTo('.tt');
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">54,120</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">12,650</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">32,390</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media" id="clicker">
  <div class="media-body">
    <h3 class="mb-0">76,770</h3>
    <span class="text-uppercase font-size-xs">total</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tt">

</div>
```